# How to subscribe/consume multiple topics from multiple subscriptions programmatically with Dapr pub/sub component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, publish-subscribe, azure-servicebus-topics, dapr

[Dapr doc shows](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/subscription-methods/#programmatic-subscriptions) how to programmatically subscribe and consume a topic from a subscription, along with an ASP.NET Web API project.

I am using Azure Service Bus Topics and an Web API running in .NET 8.

I define the connection string for the Azure Service Bus and the subscription name (in `consumerID` metadata key value) in the yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
    name: dapr-pubsub-component
spec:
    type: pubsub.azure.servicebus.topics
    version: v1
    metadata:
    - name: connectionString
      value: [YOUR_SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING]
    - name: consumerID
      value: dapr-demo-subscription-1
```

Then in the Web API project, I install `Dapr.AspNetCore` Nuget, and add Dapr into the MVC pipeline by:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...

        builder.Services.AddControllers()
            .AddDapr();

        ...
    }
}
```

And then I defined a controller and an action denoted to handle any topics from the subscription I defined in yaml file at the beginning:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/vehicles")]
public class VehicleSubscriberController : ControllerBase
{
    // "dapr-pubsub-component" is the pubsub component name I defined in the yaml
    // "vehicle-created-topic" is the topic name I subscribe
    [Topic("dapr-pubsub-component", "vehicle-created-topic")]
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IActionResult VehicleCreated(VehicleCreated @event)
    {
        if (@event is not null)
        {
            // Handle the event
            return Ok();
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    [Topic("dapr-pubsub-component", "vehicle-ownership-changed-topic")]
    [HttpPatch("/{vehicleId}/ownership")]
    ...
}
```

Lastly, when I run the `dapr run` command:

```
dapr run
  --app-id dapr-subscriber-demo
  --app-port 5219
  --resources-path ..\..\components\pubsub\azure\servicebus\topics\
  -- dotnet run
```

I can see from the logs that the events have been consumed.

This is working great, and I can add as many controllers and actions I want, to consume as many topics I want, as long as they're coming from the same subscription `dapr-demo-subscription-1`.

But how can I consume different topics from a different subscription from the same Azure Service Bus? And I want to keep all the consumers in the same Web API project.